# Routing - why permalink "john.green" doesn't work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, url, routes, permalinks

In `routes.rb` I have set up

> match "member/:permalink" => "accounts#profile"

when the user's url name is `john-green`, `john_green`, `johngreen`, everything is working fine, but when the url name is `john.green`, so as the permalink is taken just the first part - `john`
Specifically, from the Rails debug window:

```
Request

Parameters:

{"permalink"=>"john",
 "format"=>"green"}
```

Why is not accepted the `.` (dot) in the permalink? Exist any feature for using that?
**EDIT** when I use

```
  match "member/:permalink" => "accounts#profile", 
        :requirements       => { :permalink => /.+/ }
```

I get

```
{"requirements"=>{"permalink"=>/.+/},
 "permalink"=>"john",
 "format"=>"green"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Rails treats everything after the dot as a format and looks like there's no easy way of overriding this behavior. But there's a bit dirty workaround that uses `:requirements` option:

```
match 'member/:permalink' => 'accounts#profile', 
      :constraints        => { :permalink => /.+/ }
```

By adding greedy regexp for the `:permalink` parameter you make Rails pass everything it finds after the `member/` substring in the path into `params[:permalink]`.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but unfortunately the url name is still separated to two parts (I updated my original post)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It should be `constraints`, not `requirements`. Updated and tested the answer - works fine for me on Rails 3.2.3.